# Do not know where I'm wrong in the task

Tags: arrays, string, recursion

For some n, we have to determine number of different strings made only of '0' and '1' in which there is no two adjacent '1'.(Size of string is n) Sorry for my bad english.
This is my attempt:

```
long Num(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else if(n==1)
        return 2;
    else if(n==2)
        return 3;
    else if(n==3)
        return 5;
    else
        return 2*Num(n-2) + Num(n-3);
};
```

Comment: You could post some example of input, expected outpout and actual outpout.

Comment: you need to be specific in your questions.... you've left a lot of details out.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem :

To find out the number of possible binary strings of length n, having no consecutive 1's.

### Input/Output :

Input:  N = 2
Output: 3
// The 3 strings are 00, 01, 10

Input: N = 3
Output: 5
// The 5 strings are 000, 001, 010, 100, 101

### Approach :

Let a[i] be the number of binary strings of length i which do not contain any two consecutive 1’s and which end in 0. Similarly, let b[i] be the number of such strings which end in 1. We can append either 0 or 1 to a string ending in 0, but we can only append 0 to a string ending in 1. This yields the recurrence relation:

```
a[i] = a[i - 1] + b[i - 1]
b[i] = a[i - 1]
```

The base cases of above recurrence are a[1] = b[1] = 1. The total number of strings of length i is just a[i] + b[i]. While using array i (length of string) will be 1 less, for array's zero position.

### Solution :

```
int countStrings(int n)
{
    int a[] = new int [n];
    int b[] = new int [n];
    a[0] = b[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + b[i-1];
        b[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    return a[n-1] + b[n-1];
}
```

For more details see http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-binary-strings-without-consecutive-1s/